# Laravel URL Filtering with GET

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-request

I am building a simple Laravel routing to display an array when someone goes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/planets`

But I need to make a filter to check the array on what request has been send on the URL. For example: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/planets?planet=mars`

I need to make sure that if a GET parameter is present, you filter the array based on whether the planet name is in it. This way we can filter the results of the page a little faster.

The code I currently have Web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/planets', function () {
    
    $planets = [
        [
            'name' => 'Mars',
            'description' => 'Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and the second-smallest planet in the Solar System, being larger than only Mercury.'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Venus',
            'description' => 'Venus is the second planet from the Sun. It is named after the Roman goddess of love and beauty.'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Earth',
            'description' => 'Our home planet is the third planet from the Sun, and the only place we know of so far thats inhabited by living things.'
        ]
    ];
    
    return view('welcome', ['planets'=>$planets]);
});
```

And my welcome blade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
            html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a{background-color:transparent}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji;line-height:1.5}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;border:0 solid #e2e8f0}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}video{max-width:100%;height:auto}.bg-white{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#fff;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--bg-opacity))}.bg-gray-100{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#f7fafc;background-color:rgba(247,250,252,var(--bg-opacity))}.border-gray-200{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#edf2f7;border-color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--border-opacity))}.border-t{border-top-width:1px}.flex{display:flex}.grid{display:grid}.hidden{display:none}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-center{justify-content:center}.font-semibold{font-weight:600}.h-5{height:1.25rem}.h-8{height:2rem}.h-16{height:4rem}.text-sm{font-size:.875rem}.text-lg{font-size:1.125rem}.leading-7{line-height:1.75rem}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.ml-1{margin-left:.25rem}.mt-2{margin-top:.5rem}.mr-2{margin-right:.5rem}.ml-2{margin-left:.5rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.ml-4{margin-left:1rem}.mt-8{margin-top:2rem}.ml-12{margin-left:3rem}.-mt-px{margin-top:-1px}.max-w-6xl{max-width:72rem}.min-h-screen{min-height:100vh}.overflow-hidden{overflow:hidden}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.py-4{padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}.px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.pt-8{padding-top:2rem}.fixed{position:fixed}.relative{position:relative}.top-0{top:0}.right-0{right:0}.shadow{box-shadow:0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-gray-200{--text-opacity:1;color:#edf2f7;color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-300{--text-opacity:1;color:#e2e8f0;color:rgba(226,232,240,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-500{--text-opacity:1;color:#a0aec0;color:rgba(160,174,192,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-600{--text-opacity:1;color:#718096;color:rgba(113,128,150,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-700{--text-opacity:1;color:#4a5568;color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-900{--text-opacity:1;color:#1a202c;color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--text-opacity))}.underline{text-decoration:underline}.antialiased{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.w-5{width:1.25rem}.w-8{width:2rem}.w-auto{width:auto}.grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1,minmax(0,1fr))}@media (min-width:640px){.sm\:rounded-lg{border-radius:.5rem}.sm\:block{display:block}.sm\:items-center{align-items:center}.sm\:justify-start{justify-content:flex-start}.sm\:justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.sm\:h-20{height:5rem}.sm\:ml-0{margin-left:0}.sm\:px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.sm\:pt-0{padding-top:0}.sm\:text-left{text-align:left}.sm\:text-right{text-align:right}}@media (min-width:768px){.md\:border-t-0{border-top-width:0}.md\:border-l{border-left-width:1px}.md\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(0,1fr))}}@media (min-width:1024px){.lg\:px-8{padding-left:2rem;padding-right:2rem}}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){.dark\:bg-gray-800{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#2d3748;background-color:rgba(45,55,72,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:bg-gray-900{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#1a202c;background-color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:border-gray-700{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#4a5568;border-color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--border-opacity))}.dark\:text-white{--text-opacity:1;color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-500{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:#6b7280;color:rgba(107,114,128,var(--tw-text-opacity))}}
        </style>

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                font-weight: bolder;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">

@foreach ($planets as $planet)
    <ul>
        <li>{{$planet['name']}}</li>
        <p>{{$planet['description']}}</p>
    </ul>
@endforeach
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? It looks like you didn't try anything.

Comment: I tried multiple things but they all didnt work.... so i deleted them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laravel [`Illuminate\Http\Request`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests) object has a [`query`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string) method on it that allows you access to query string parameters.

```
$request->query('param');
```

So for your scenario and given the URL `example.com/planets?names=mars,earth`, you would grab the planet names as follows:

```
$names = $request->query('names');
```

That would result in the `$names` variable having the string value `mars,earth`.

From here you want to use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to separate out the individual names:

```
$names = explode(',', $request->query('names');
```

This time `$names` is an array with two elements, `mars` and `earth`.

Then you can use the [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherein) method available on Laravel [`Collections`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) to filter your planets to just those found in the `$names` array.

```
$planets = collect($planets)
    ->whereIn('name', array_map(fn($name) => strtolower($name), $names))
    ->all();
```

Note that for the above to work I have done two things.

1. I made all the planet names in your `$planets` array lower case
2. I use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to convert the query parameter values to lower case for comparing with the `$planets` array

This should mitigate casing issues (so people typing `mars`, `MARS` or other variations) should be captured correctly.

Put it all together and you should have something like the following:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/planets', function (Request $request) {

    $planets = [
        [
            'name' => 'mars',
            'description' => 'Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and the second-smallest planet in the Solar System, being larger than only Mercury.'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'venus',
            'description' => 'Venus is the second planet from the Sun. It is named after the Roman goddess of love and beauty.'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'earth',
            'description' => 'Our home planet is the third planet from the Sun, and the only place we know of so far thats inhabited by living things.'
        ]
    ];

    if ($request->query('names')) {
        $names = explode(',', $request->query('names'));
        $planets = collect($planets)->whereIn('name', array_map(fn($name) => strtolower($name), $names))->all();
    }

    return view('welcome', compact('planets'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$uri_path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$uri_parts = explode('=', $uri_path);
$request_url = end($uri_parts);
dd($request_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

On your backend you can find out whether you have a GET parameter via

`isset($_GET["planet"])`

or via

`Input::get('start')`

Let's assume that you have a `$planet` object that's defaulted to `null` and which is overriden by the GET parameter if it's truey.

```
if (!!$planet) {
    $planets = [$planet]
}
```